# Multiple request for 1 endpoint block request to other endpoints

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, next.js, devextreme

I need to upload multiple pdf’s to an endpoint. 
Currently I am bombarding api with 1 pdf per 1 request (using devextreme-react file uploader)
It works fine for 3-5 request but more than that queues them into pending. 
The problem is that I also still need an api to handle other endpoints. 
Maybe something like telling the browser “use up to 3 parallel requests for this endpoint and leave the rest pending but when I request other endpoints then handle them immidiately”.
How to do that?
My stack is React with Next, axios for request, Django Rest Framework on Back end.

Comment: why...can't you just send multiple pdf files over in one request? Why bombard each subsequent pdf with it's own API? Just use `multiple` attribute in your file input field and send all files in one go.

Comment: That's how https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/FileUploader/FileUploading/React/Light/ handles it. I've thought about extracting it's input ... but I honestly don't know how to and whether it's good idea to let endpoint process f.e 4GB of data.